# Attention CV users with Statistics blogs: Review CV in your area of specialization

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Some of the community members in here maintain some excellent blogs, complementing some of the expertise on here, discussing a range of CV topics from R to applied methods. Are community members interested in reviewing CV.SE on their blogs in their area of specialization?

Comment: What is "Stack Exchange CHAOS team"? :-)

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it seems a bit odd you are doing this all on your own (unless you have consulted with moderators that is invisible to me). I would also mention that we have a devoted chat room, [Skewed Distribution](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/549/skewed-distribution), which is appropriate for discussion related to the blog.

Comment: @chl We're working on growing our communities while maintaining high quality membership.

Comment: @Andy W I'm aware of Skewed Distribution and now that it has users present we can discuss in there.

Comment: @seth even without "users present" you can leave messages in a chat room and others can respond to them -- it is stateful.

Comment: @Seth: could you clarify what you mean by "partnering with CV.SE on their blogs"?

Comment: @raegtin We would invite authors to review CV from their area of expertise.

Comment: @Seth By review CV you mean just talk about and promote CV?

Comment: @raegtin The intention behind this post was to invite statisticians to discuss the usefulness of CV in their work/ areas of particular strength and weakness of the site. Intelligent reviews "should" spark some effort to bring more expertise to an area of weakness. Doesn't that enhance the utility of CV for everyone?

Comment: @Seth Oh, yeah, I wasn't disparaging the idea :), just wasn't sure what you meant.

Comment: @Seth Actually, I guess I'm still not sure what you mean =D. Do you mean promoting CV on our own personal blogs, or do you mean you're looking for community members here to write posts for CV's blog?

Comment: @raegtin Great comment, thanks. In this post I'm inviting you to review CV on your personal blog! Though generally, absolutely contribute to the CV blog- post in Skewed Distribution (chat) or contact our friendly neighborhood mod for CV blog entries.

Answer (score 4):

I would be - my blog is mainly on applied research questions, with the occasional coding related posts in SAS or R.

Comment: @EpiGrad , feel free to stop by the Skewed Distribution chat room and we will give you access to the blogging platform to post if you would like. I can't see your blog at the moment (work filter), but given the quality of your answers on the site I'm plenty confident you would be able to make quality contributions to the blog.

Comment: @Andy W - I'd be happy to. I'm on Skewed Distribution at the moment.

Comment: @Seth Rogers My email is in my profile :)

Answer (score 4):

- I encourage research students to ask questions on the site. I direct [my students to this page](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-ask-me-statistics-question.html) that outlines the benefits of using a site like Cross Validated.